# Can I use NPX with yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, package-managers, npx, yarn-workspaces

I have a project that I am using `yarn` for. I've installed all my packages using `yarn`, I run `yarn dev` and so on. Now I'm following a tutorial that requires me to use `npx` to set up a package. - I'm wondering if I can just go ahead with this or if I will end up mixing things up here, as `npx`, as far as I know, is related to `npm` ?

Comment: `npx` does nothing more than invoking a script on a `npm` repository (which yarn also uses) without actually installing it (globally). It can be used interchangeable with yarn.

Comment: Also you can use yarn instead of npx.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `instead of` but also `with it` ? as in: can I today install everything with `yarn`, tomorrow use an `npx` command and then next week use `yarn add xxx` again?

Comment: I was just wondering if I should do this. I just used `npx` for `npx eslint init`. It created a `package-lock.json` (along with other configs and added dependencies), then I deleted the `package-lock.json` and ran `yarn` after to properly install. Seems like it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. `npx` will run the executable from your `node_modules` directory if it is installed there. If it is not, it will install the executable into a different location. It will not interfere with `yarn` operations.

With Yarn 2, you can also use `dlx`. For example:

```bash
yarn dlx create-react-app ./my-app
```

See https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx for information and options.

Comment: Since i came across this question today, check out [yarn dlx <comman>](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx) and the blog post of [yarn2](https://yarnpkg.dev/releases/2-0/#new-command-yarn-dlx). Please notice this only works for yarn2 or higher.